# misconfigured csrf in nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, csrf

Hi guys i just started using csrf
But when i use it and try to request to my server api
I got this error

```
[Nest] 16868  - 06/11/2023, 5:32:01 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] misconfigured csrf
```

this is my main.ts

```
async function bootstrap() {
  try {
    const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule, { cors: true });
    const logger = new Logger(bootstrap.name);

    // Middleware
    app.use(csurf());
    app.use(helmet());

    // Pipes
    app.useGlobalPipes(
      new ValidationPipe({
        whitelist: true,
      }),
    );

    // App
    await app.listen(3000);

  } catch (error) {
    Logger.error(`❌  Couldn't start the server, ${error}`);
    process.exit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Which csrf package are you using? `csurf` (from express), while deprecated, requires a session storage or a cookie parser to function